# How to get Android's gateway/router IP through Shell?

Tags: android, shell

I typically use `getprop net.dns1` to get the gateway/router IP but this doesn't work when the router and the DNS has difference IP addrs. What r the other methods to get gateway/router IP through Shell?

btw, if I use `route` the output will show the gateway IP as `*` or `0.0.0.0` if I use `route -n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one or multiple gateways this will return the first one to you. `arp | awk 'FNR == 1 {print $2}' | tr -d '()'`